# How to ensure that my class Initialize method is called only once, what would be the best approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, singleton, unity-container

I'm currently using Unity IoC Container and here is my AppConfig class. As you can see the Initialize method should be called only once and I have used double lock checking to ensure that.

What would be the best way to implement achieve this if my approach is not the best way?

```
public interface IAppConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the admin username.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The admin username.</value>
    string AdminUsername { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the admin password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The admin password.</value>
    string AdminPassword { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes this instance.
    /// </summary>
    void Initialize();
}

/// <summary>
/// A singleton App config which helps reading from web.config
/// its lifetime is controlled by Unity.
/// </summary>
public class AppConfig : IAppConfig
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// the injectable config manager
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IConfigManager _configManager;

    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    private static readonly object LockObject = new object();

    private static bool _initialized = false;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AppConfig"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public AppConfig(IConfigManager configManager, ILogger logger)
    {
        this._configManager = configManager;
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the admin username.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The admin username.</value>
    public string AdminUsername { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the admin password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The admin password.</value>
    public string AdminPassword { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void Initialize()
    {
        if (_initialized)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Initialize method should be called only once");
        }

        lock(LockObject)
        {
            if (_initialized) return;

            var adminUserNameSetting = _configManager.AppSettings[ConfigKeys.AdminUsername];

            if (adminUserNameSetting == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("AdminUsername key not found");
            }

            this.AdminUsername = adminUserNameSetting.Value;

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.AdminUsername))
            {
                _logger.LogError("AdminUsername not found");
            }

            // log
            var adminPasswordSetting = _configManager.AppSettings[ConfigKeys.AdminPassword];

            if (adminPasswordSetting == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("AdminPassword key not found");
            }

            this.AdminPassword = adminPasswordSetting.Value;

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.AdminPassword))
            {
                _logger.LogError("AdminPassword not found");
            }
            _initialized = true;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In the Unity, I'm using the below code:

```
// IAppConfig
container.RegisterType<IAppConfig, AppConfig>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
                                              new InjectionConstructor(configManager,
                                                                       logger));
var appConfig = container.Resolve<IAppConfig>();
appConfig.Initialize();
```

Comment: Why don't you just call it once. What's up with this super over the top defensive programming.

Comment: I will call it once but I'd like to make sure it's called once and not twice by mistake!

Comment: static analysis of source code is a better solution then hacking your source code to pieces with locking mechanisms.

Comment: TL;DR, call it from the constructor?

Comment: The problem with calling it from constructor is that it becomes less unit testable.

Answer (score 3):

I think an `Initalize()` method tastes more like an implementation issue. And that means that maybe it shouldn't be in the interface at all.

Initializing an instance is best left to the constructor.

If you really need a delayed Initialize then you solution with a bool and a lock seems OK.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I'd usually keep my constructor clean and use it mainly to set private fields and use delayed initialization if other properties have to be calculated or validated or initialized. Eager Initialization vs Delayed Initialization.

Comment: If other properties have to be calculated or validated or initialized _later_, why don't you implement lazy-loading on those properties, so that the class takes care of that effort, not the calling code? That's half the point of encapsulation.

Comment: Because all those properties should be initialized together so lazy-loading wouldn't work. Initially I was using eager initialization in the constructor but I thought I'd make it delayed initialization for the reason mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by what you are doing in the Initialize method, I think what you need to look into is registering that class as a singleton and persisting the container.    You can see an example of doing this here:

http://gunnarpeipman.com/2008/04/unity-and-singletons/

Comment: I have already registered the class as singleton; did you read my code properly?

Comment: A singleton would be my instinct as well and yes he did read your code correctly as your AppConfig class does not follow the singleton pattern for C# as shown by the public constructor.

Comment: Like I said, it's already singleton! its lifetime is controlled by Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you're relying on Unity to ensure that you class is a singleton. Although the code pattern for C# is quite easy. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx). Then call initialisation code in the constructor.

In any case I would declare your initialization flag volatile as the code stands atmo.

Comment: The reason volatile hasn't been used is because it is not needed as I'm using double checking lock. Volatile ensures that one thread retrieves the most up-to-date value written by another thread and the code ensures it without volatile.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have a static class instance variable that checks to see if it has been initialized in the get accessor. Access the class through the instance property and you will control how many times the class is initialized. This is pretty much the default C# singleton pattern:

```
public static class MySingleton 
{
    private static Mutex instanceLock = new Mutex();

    private static MySingleton instance;
    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            instanceLock.WaitOne();
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = new MySingleton();
            }
            instanceLock.ReleaseMutex();
            return instance;
         }
    }

    private MySingleton()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // Initialize
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    private MySingleton singleton = MySingleton.Instance;
}
```

Comment: that is not the default .net pattern. You can just new up the instance in your "private static MySingleton = new MySingleton()" and not need any of that code. https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Singleton